# Creating Task Reminders with Process Builder

Tags: workflow, process-builder, process

I created a process builder process so every time I a lead an automatic task is created ..
How do I automate that the task should be assign next day (Next day of Lead Created Day).

Answer (score 1):

You can use "scheduled actions" instead of "immediate actions"  when you build the process

Comment: Actually I am trying 
Due Date = [Lead].CreatedDate + 1

But it's not working

Comment: Do you mean the task is not getting created or the due date is incorrect?

Comment: The Lead is from web to lead which is not created so the task also not created